# Android, ListView, удержание

Tags: android-sdk, android

Подскажите, какой слушатель используется, для получения элемента ListView, на который было произведено долгое нажатие?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Долгое нажатие обычно обрабатывается с помощью OnItemLongClickListener.